# converting a SQL statement to LINQ query on a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, datatable, asenumerable

I am studying that Linq to DataTable,Lambda.
Because is difficult want to change sql to linq,Lambda, is not doing.

Below the SQL code is member list that remove telephone number repetition.
I will thank if help.

```
SELECT A.no, B.name, B.userId, B.homeTel2    
FROM

    (  SELECT homeTel2, min(no) NO
       FROM  OF_Member
       GROUP BY homeTel2 
    ) A
    INNER JOIN OF_Member B
        ON A.NO = B.NO
```

Progressing work  ============

var objectName =from t in mMemberTable.AsEnumerable()
    group t by t.Field("homeTel2")

Comment: I modified the question. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link:

[Linq to Entities simple group query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358082/linq-to-entities-simple-group-query)

[converting ms sql “group by” query to linq to sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554349/converting-ms-sql-group-by-query-to-linq-to-sql)

```
                var objectName =from t in mMemberTable.AsEnumerable()
                group t by t.Field<string>("homeTel2") into groups
                select groups;
```

Hope this helps,

Regards

Comment: Yup..make your sql more simple..and.linq will help you to minimize coding sql statement...

Comment: ^^; Thank you. but My ideas may be the simplest cord that this code prevents member repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tool called LINQ Pad. This is the best tool so far for writing and testing sql/LINQ queries and moreover it is free. It also allows you to convert your queries from LINQ to SQL and vice-versa.

http://www.linqpad.net

Comment: I know LINQPad have fuction that LINQ to SQL, but does not have fuction that SQL to LINQ.